# What is maximum of $\frac{x^2+y^2+z^2}{xy+xz+yz}$ when $x, y, z \in [1, 2]$?

Tags: inequality, optimization, convex-analysis, contest-math, convexity-inequality

If we have real numbers $x, y, z \in [1, 2]$ then what is the maximum of

$$\frac{x^2+y^2+z^2}{xy+xz+yz}$$

I tried to use substitution $x=\frac{3+\sin X}{2}$, $y=\frac{3+\sin Y}{2}$ and $z=\frac{3+\sin Z}{2}$. But the expression became too messy. This is an Olympiad problem (I don't know the source) and I am not allowed to use calculus. I hope someone can provide an insight to this problem!

Comment: Why that substitution?  Anyway, the max appears to occur when two of the variables are $1$ and the other is $2$.  The expression suggests there's probably a "symmetry" that could be exploited, but nothing jumps out at me.  Are you allowed to use calculus?

Comment: I have used similar substitution for easier problems and sometimes worked! But not for this! No it's an Olympiad problem! I am not allowed to use calculus!

Comment: Please update the question to make it clear that calculus use is NOT allowed

Comment: i think it must be $$\frac{x^2+y^2+z^2}{xy+yz+zx}\le \frac{6}{5}$$

Comment: How did you get it?

Comment: @Dedaha, likely with WolframAlpha.  He's known for using it, and I used it and got the same thing.

Comment: If you manage to prove that $f(x,y,z)=\frac{x^2+y^2+z^2}{xy+xz+yz}$ is (midpoint-)convex, then its maximum over the cube $[1,2]^3$ is surely achieved at a vertex. Then it is straightforward to understand *which* vertex.

Comment: Not sure if this helps but I noticed that $(x+y)^2 + (x+z)^2 + (y+z)^2 = 2(x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + xy + xz + yz)$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $k$ is a maximal value and $f(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2-k(xy+xz+yz)$.

Since, $f$ is a convex function of $x$, of $y$ and of $z$, we obtain:
$$0=\max_{\{x,y,z\}\subset[1,2]}f=\max_{\{x,y,z\}\subset\{1,2\}}f$$,
which for $x=y=1$ and $z=2$ gives $k=\frac{6}{5}$ and we are done!

Comment: Nice idea, but isn't the convexity of $f$ depending on the positive-definiteness of the matrix $$\begin{pmatrix}1 & -k/2 & -k/2 \\ -k/2 & 1 & -k/2 \\ -k/2 & -k/2 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$ ? That puts some restrictions on $k$ for your approach to work.

Comment: This is heavy for me!

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio I don't say that $f$ is a convex function. I say that $f$ is a convex function of $x$, of $y$ and of $z$. Which says that $f$ gets a maximal value for an extremal value of $x$, of $y$ and of $z$, which happens for $\{x,y,z\}=\{1,2\}$.

Comment: @Dedaha See my answer to Jack D'Aurizio. Ask your question. I am ready to help.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg: oh, coordinate-wise convex, that is subtle. (+1)

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg why $f$ is a convex function?

Comment: @Dedaha: it is not granted to be a convex function *tout court*, but for fixed values of $y$ and $x$ we have that $f(x,y,z)$ is a convex function of the $x$-variable and so on.

Comment: @Dedaha $f$ is a convex function of $x$ because (for example) $\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^2}=2>0$.

Comment: @Dedaha when fixing $y,z$, $f$ will become a positive multiple of $$\frac{x^2+a}{x+b}=\frac{(x+b)^2-2b(x+b)+b^2+a}{x+b}=(x+b)+\frac{b^2+a}{x+b}-2b$$ for some $a,b>0$. Since $x\in[1,2]$, it is clear $f$ is convex in $x$.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Why maximum of $f$ is $0$?

Comment: @Dedaha Because the maximal value, which you want is $k$. In another words, because $\frac{x^2+y^2+z^2}{xy+xz+yz}\leq k$, where $k$ is a maximal value.